# Странное поведение типов в Golang

Tags: golang, интерфейс

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type cat struct{}

func (c cat) say() {
    fmt.Println("meow")
}

type animal interface {
    say()
}

func main() {
    var a animal = cat{}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a)) // main.cat
    var b cat = a
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b)) // main.cat
}
```

В этом коде ошибка в строке "var b cat = a" - "cannot use a (type animal) as type cat in assignment: need type assertion", но если убрать "cat", оба типа переменных a и b выведут main.cat.

Может ли кто-то объяснить, почему переменная a имеет тип animal в ошибке, и тип cat в выводе?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что animal — интерфейсный тип.  Конкретные
типы, реализующие интерфейсы, можно конвертировать в интерфейсные, но не
наоборот, так как в интерфейсном значении может лежать другая
реализация.  Для такой конвертации нужно утверждение типа (англ «*type
assertion*»):

```golang
var b cat = a.(cat)
```

См. документацию:

- [*Assignability*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)
- [*Type Assertions*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)